# Summation solution clarification

Tags: summation, contest-math

I was reading through a solution for a problem and it stated this: $$\sum_{a_1 = 0}^\infty \sum_{a_2 = 0}^\infty \dotsb \sum_{a_7 = 0}^\infty \left( \frac{a_1}{3^{a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_7}} + \frac{a_2}{3^{a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_7}} + \dots + \frac{a_7}{3^{a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_7}} \right) = 7 \sum_{a_1 = 0}^\infty \sum_{a_2 = 0}^\infty \dotsb \sum_{a_7 = 0}^\infty \frac{a_1}{3^{a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_7}}.$$ I do have an inkling why this true—probably more of an intuition to be honest, but I don't fully understand. Can anybody clarify? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Symmetry of the variables.

Comment: What does that specifically mean? Thanks.

Comment: For a 'lite' version, for instance, do you buy $\sum_{x=1}^{4} \sum_{y=1}^{4} \frac{x+y}{x^2+y^2}=2\sum_{x=1}^{4} \sum_{y=1}^{4} \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$?

Comment: I have seen many times this being used and have used it myself, but I don't specifically get what is true since it's hard for me to visualize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to see what's going on it is sufficient to consider double series. Assuming the series are absolutely convergent, we obtain

> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{a_1=0}^{\infty}}\color{blue}{\sum_{a_2=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_1+a_2}{3^{a_1+a_2}}}
> &=\sum_{a_1=0}^{\infty}\sum_{a_2=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_1}{3^{a_1+a_2}}+\sum_{a_1=0}^{\infty}\sum_{a_2=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_2}{3^{a_1+a_2}}\\
> &=\sum_{a_1=0}^{\infty}\sum_{a_2=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_1}{3^{a_1+a_2}}+\sum_{a_2=0}^{\infty}\sum_{a_1=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_1}{3^{a_2+a_1}}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{a_1=0}^{\infty}\sum_{a_2=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_1}{3^{a_1+a_2}}+\sum_{a_1=0}^{\infty}\sum_{a_2=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_1}{3^{a_1+a_2}}\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=2\sum_{a_1=0}^{\infty}\sum_{a_2=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_1}{3^{a_1+a_2}}}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we rename in the right-most double series $a_1$ with $a_2$ and $a_2$ with $a_1$.
- In (2) we reorder it.